# Can I use PHP output buffering in between creating a variable and using it?

Tags: php

I don't think I understand how PHP output buffering works well enough to know whether this is possible: I want to do the following, in this order:

1. Declare a PHP variable $foo
2. Begin and end an output buffer to declare a variable $bar
3. Use the variable $foo

When I try to use $foo the second time, it appears I inadvertently cleared it.

Code example:

```
<?php
$foo = 'some value';
ob_start();
include('some_file.php');
//I want to use output buffering since some_file.php has a number of echo statements that I want to concatenate into one variable.  Maybe there's a better way?
$bar = ob_get_clean();
ob_end_flush();
echo $bar;
echo $foo;
?>
```

In the example above, $bar works fine but $foo is undefined at the end.  I don't think I understand the underlying concepts well enough to know exactly what's going on in the code here.  I want to be able to use the buffer (or some other method?) to make all the echo statements in some_file.php go to a single string, while preserving the variables from the previous PHP code.  Is there a way to do this?

Comment: `$foo` should still be declared. Do you overwrite it in `some_file.php`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> In the example above, $bar works fine but $foo is undefined at the end

You are probably `unset`ting it inside `some_file.php`. Your script works fine otherwise. You can also `return` the output from the other file via `return` inside `some_file.php`:

```
// some_file.php
...
return $output;

// main file
...
$bar = include('some_file.php');
```

Comment: Ha!  Thanks for this.  $foo was a basic variable name that I inadvertently initialized and used in some_file.php